# Change private IP address without losing internet access

Tags: ubuntu, ip, network-interface, vmware, ifconfig

I start with the following:

```
ens33     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:03:a8:56  
          inet addr:192.168.0.161  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::dfa6:820:b035:a36a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:78 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4957 (4.9 KB)  TX bytes:8702 (8.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:204 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:204 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15089 (15.0 KB)  TX bytes:15089 (15.0 KB)
```

And **I want to set my address to a specific value, so that I can identify it easily from other systems when SSHing**. I run:

```
ifconfig ens33 192.168.10.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
route add default gw 192.168.10.1
```

And the result is:

```
ens33     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:03:a8:56  
          inet addr:192.168.10.2  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::dfa6:820:b035:a36a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:147 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:146 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:20559 (20.5 KB)  TX bytes:14302 (14.3 KB)
```

As a result, I'm **losing internet connection**, and **the machine is also not discoverable** within the network.

What am I doing wrong?

### Update 1

Per @Tomasz's suggestion, I changed the router's mask to `255.255.0.0`. I am now running:

```
ifconfig ens33 192.168.10.2 netmask 255.255.0.0 up
route add default gw 192.168.10.1 ens33
```

Unfortunately, same effect.

Comment: And I guess you should add `up` at the end of the `ifconfig` line.

Comment: What OS is that? Are you using the NetworkManager?

Comment: It's Ubuntu running in VMWare. These are the default values.

Comment: That's a strange IP for a VM. Is the connection bridged? What IP do you have on the host machine (the "outer" OS)?

Comment: Yes, it's bridged. I wanted it to be independent of the host OS.

Comment: Is this your router's new IP? `192.168.10.1`?

Comment: My router's IP is `192.168.0.1`. Oh shoot...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are allowed to assign yourself an IP, and I don't know if you've been doing this correctly, your netmask:

```
Mask:255.255.255.0
```

In combination with your working IP:

```
192.168.0.161
```

Leaves you with this subnet: `192.168.0.0/24`, which means you in no way could assign yourself any IP starting `192.168.10.`. You could only change the last number in `192.168.0.161`.

Comment: Fair point. I just updated my router's mask to `255.255.0.0` and I'm still having the same problem. I also added the `up` at the end of the command.